# Accessing dictionary value by index in python

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I would like to get the value by key index from a Python dictionary. Is there a way to get it something like this?

```
dic = {}
value_at_index = dic.ElementAt(index)
```

where `index` is an integer

Comment: For later visitors of this post: 
Getting value by index: `dic.values()[index]`
Getting key by index: `dic.keys()[index]`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In Python versions before 3.7 dictionaries were inherently unordered, so what you're asking to do doesn't really make sense.

If you really, really know what you're doing, use

```
value_at_index = list(dic.values())[index]
```

Bear in mind that prior to Python 3.7 adding or removing an element can potentially change the index of every other element.

Comment: Though `OrderedDict` is available if you have the ability to change the original data construction.

Comment: >> that adding or removing an element can potentially change the index of every other element. Yes I know that, this is a common sense for many iterators in many languages.

Comment: Yes, what exactly I want an index for is to get a random values within  available key range, just to implement my algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call the value at a given index "random".

Comment: I could not fit the full reply in here, but check out my answer below that iterates instead of creating a list.  It is more accurate than this chosen answer.

Comment: Doing this sort of thing is useful for inspecting a running program's dictionary when you might not necessarily know a key. i.e dict.values()[0] to see an example of a value.

Comment: `dic.values()[index]` I obtain 'dict_values' object does not support indexing ..... ? (python 3.6)

Comment: @B.M. you can do what mohammed ali shaik suggests below.

Comment: `TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: `list(dic.values())[index]` works

Comment: This syntax does not work in Python 3.6.
Use: 
value_at_index = list(dic.values())[index]
This converts the returned dictionary view to a bona fide list.

Comment: I have successfully sliced my sorted dict using keys as an index...  such as    keywords.keys()[startid:endid]    it would be a snap to make the startid value hold your random number.  From this key you can get all the data you want.  :)

Answer (score 17):

Let us take an example of dictionary:

```
numbers = {'first':0, 'second':1, 'third':3}
```

When I did

```
numbers.values()[index]
```

I got an error:'dict_values' object does not support indexing

When I did

```
numbers.itervalues()
```

to iterate and extract the values it is also giving an error:'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Hence I came up with new way of accessing dictionary elements by index just by converting them to tuples.

```
tuple(numbers.items())[key_index][value_index]
```

for example:

```
tuple(numbers.items())[0][0] gives 'first'
```

if u want to edit the values or sort the values the tuple object does not allow the item assignment. In this case you can use

```
list(list(numbers.items())[index])
```

Comment: This works perfectly with python 3, thank you!

Comment: does not work when the index is a string ... `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Answer (score 9):

If you really just want a random value from the available key range, use `random.choice` on the dictionary's values (converted to list form, if Python 3).

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>>> choice(list(d.values()))
```

Answer (score 7):

While you can do

```
value = d.values()[index]
```

It should be faster to do

```
value = next( v for i, v in enumerate(d.itervalues()) if i == index )
```

edit: I just timed it using a dict of len 100,000,000 checking for the index at the very end, and the 1st/values() version took 169 seconds whereas the 2nd/next() version took 32 seconds.

Also, note that this assumes that your index is not negative