# Order dictionary index in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have created a order dictionary and could not get the index out of it.
I have gone through the below url but not working.

> [Accessing dictionary value by index in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114843/accessing-dictionary-value-by-index-in-python)

Here is my code and output.

```
line_1 = OrderedDict((('A1', "Miyapur"), ('A2', "JNTU College"), ('A3', "KPHB Colony"),
                ('A4', "Kukatpally"), ('A5', "Balanagar"), ('A6', "Moosapet"),
                ('A7', "Bharat Nagar"), ('A8', "Erragadda"), ('A9', "ESI Hospital"),
                ('A10', "S R Nagar"), ('X1', "Ameerpet"), ('A12', "Punjagutta"),
                ('A13', "Irrum Manzil"), ('A14', "Khairatabad"), ('A15', "Lakdikapul"),
                ('A16', "('Assembly"), ('A17', "Nampally"), ('A18', "Gandhi Bhavan"),
                ('A19', "Osmania Medical College"), ('X2', "MG Bus station"), ('A21', "Malakpet"),
                ('A22', "New Market"), ('A23', "Musarambagh"), ('A24', "Dilsukhnagar"),
                ('A25', "Chaitanyapuri"), ('A26', "Victoria Memorial"), ('A27', "L B Nagar")))

print(line_1.values()[1])
print(line_1[1])
print(line_1.keys()[1])
```

All the above options are not working as mentioned in the referenced link.
Any guidance is highly appreciated.
Here is the output for each print statement in the given order.

> TypeError: 'odict_values' object does not support indexing
>
> KeyError: 1
>
> TypeError: 'odict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: If you want to access values by their index in the OrderedDict's ordering, then surprisingly, OrderedDict may be a bad tool for the job. OrderedDict doesn't maintain its order in a way that facilitates efficient lookup by ordering index; you may be better off just keeping a separate list to represent the order.

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary if you need to retrieve by order (position)? Just use a list to start with.

Comment: Hi Burhan and user2357112,  actually I wanted a sequence list and key value pair at the same time so that when I give key as input, I should get both value and the position of the key in the data.

Comment: @venkat: Then you might want to incorporate the position into the value, or keep a separate key->position dict.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Python 3, dictionaries (including `OrderedDict`) return "view" objects from their `keys()` and `values()` methods. Those are iterable, but don't support indexing. The answer you linked appears to have been written for Python 2, where `keys()` and `values()` returned lists.

There are a few ways you could make the code work in Python 3. One simple (but perhaps slow) option would be to pass the view object to `list()` and then index it:

```
print(list(line_1.values())[1])
```

Another option would be to use `itertools.islice` to iterate over the view object to the desired index:

```
import itertools

print(next(itertools.islice(line_1.values(), 1, 2)))
```

But all of these solutions are pretty ugly. It may be that a dictionary is not the best data structure for you to use in this situation. If your data was in a simple list, it would be trivial to lookup any item by index (but lookup up by key would be harder).

Answer (score 6):

> TypeError: 'odict_values' object does not support indexing

You need to make it into a `list` first and then access it:

```
print(list(line_1.values())[1]) # or print([*line_1.values()][1])
```

These `view` (new in Python 3) objects act more like sets which do not support indexing they .

> KeyError: 1

The key `1` isn't in the ordered dictionary, hence the `KeyError`. Use *a valid key* like `'A1`.

> TypeError: 'odict_keys' object does not support indexing

As previously, make it into a `list` in order to index it.

---

Same applies for `line_1.items`, in order to index it you should first cast it to an object that supports indexing (`list`, `tuple`, custom etc)

Comment: how can I get the index/position of the key for example, X1 is at 10th position. So how can I get that?

Comment: Create the list from the keys and use `index` on it, i.e `list(line_1.keys()).index('X1')`.