# How can i get specific Element and key from python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i am new to python and i am having trouble on python dictionaries
this is my code:

```
dic = {"days":["mon","tue","wed"]}
print(dic[0])
```

the output am expecting is

```
"mon","tue","wed"
```

**But i keep getting this error** :

```
    print(dic[0])
KeyError: 0
```

please help me... Thank You!

Comment: `dic['days']` instead of `dic[0]`, if you want to obtain according to the insertion order, consider using `list(dic.values())[0]`.

Comment: Or this way - `print(dic['days'][0])`  It's because your `values` in the dict is a `list`.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114843/accessing-dictionary-value-by-index-in-python This duplicates that thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing dictionary value by index in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114843/accessing-dictionary-value-by-index-in-python)

Comment: i want by indexing please.... no ["days"] answers... if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks everyone i Found the answer**

```
dic = {"days":["mon","tue","wed"], "months":["jan","feb","mar"]}
print(list(dic.values())[0])
```

the output will be:

```
['mon', 'tue', 'wed']
```

**Thank you**

Comment: Note, this is will only work with python 3.7 and above ([ref](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print(dic['days'])
```

You refer to values by keys. It returns a list of elements. Then, if you want a specific element, just use:

```
print(dic['days'][0])
```

...as you would do with a normal list.

Comment: thank you... but what if i dont have to write ["days"] and by only indexing

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot access values in dictionaries by indices, only by keys. That's just how it works.

Comment: i found the answer.... i posted in here. sorry if i made too complicated

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in python are accessed via key not index as position was not guaranteed until 3.7.

```py
dic = {"days":["mon","tue","wed"]}
print(dic["days"])
```

Comment: what is there is another key and i want only the first one

Comment: What do you mean ? dicts can only have one of each key, you cannot have `dic = {"days": ["mon","tue","wed"], "days": ["thu", "fri"]}`

Comment: i found the answer.... i posted in here. sorry if i made too complicated